# How do I install Clojure 1.3 with contribs on RHEL 6.1 / JDK7?

Tags: clojure

I've been struggling a bit trying to get this to work.  Getting clojure 1.3 was a breeze, but now I've been trying to get contrib libraries to install and I get errors.  Is there a guide on how to do this correctly?

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you're using Clojure? "Installing" it or its contrib libraries can mean very different things depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I like dropping in a jar file in my lib folder and having things just work.

Comment: I have to say I'm new to maven as well.  Not new to Java or ant though. It seems that using maven is a requirement for using Clojure contrib? IS that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old clojure.contrib monolithic library is incompatible with clojure 1.3. See http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go

As for how to install libraries correctly, either write your own pom.xml and use maven or use leiningen (much easier!) - https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen

Comment: Note, *some* of the behaviour of old contrib will be different/broken under 1.3 (e.g., vars now need to have `^:dynamic` to be rebindable, integers no longer autopromote to `BigInteger` on overflow).  Much of old contrib will work just fine.  But yes, prefer new contrib libs, and note that some old contrib functionality moved into core (e.g., `string`, `java.io`).

Comment: Ouch.  First I've heard of this.  Been using 1.3 with the monolithic contribs.  Luckily I haven't run into any of the incompatibilities yet.  This new modular format looks pretty ugly honestly.  I'm disappointed in it as it looks like it's going to be a major PITA.  Please point me at some documents that show me how to make it easy/prove me wrong!

Comment: I'm not converting from 1.2 to 1.3. I just started learning Clojure and am starting from 1.3.  From reading the docs you've linked to it sounds like the process is confusing because it is.  It sounds like how 1.3 contribs is undergoing rapid changes so having a simple jar file is not maintainable.

Comment: lein works on 1.3. the 1.3 contribs are not so much going through rapid changes, as they are still being expanded with stuff from the old 1.2 contribs added as necessary when there's a maintainer. if anything, sticking to 1.2 contrib is the unmaintainable option in the long run. everything in the new 1.3 contribs will work on clojure 1.2 too, but the reverse isn't true. I think the main problem with 1.3 contrib right now is there's a lot of documentation pointing to the old way of doing stuff, so it sometimes takes time to find the correct replacement in 1.3