# how are you expected to install the clojure modular contribs?

Tags: configuration, clojure, clojure-contrib

The old monolithic clojure.contrib was available as a .jar from the same place you got the clojure .jar, and you used it by pointing your classpath at it.  As far as I can tell, the new modular contribs aren't available in the clojure .jar -- instead, they exist as source files on github.  What's the expected way for you to use them?  Say, e.g., I wanted to use something in clojure.math.numeric-tower.  What would I do?

I've found [How do I install Clojure 1.3 with contribs on RHEL 6.1 / JDK7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617541/how-do-i-install-clojure-1-3-with-contribs-on-rhel-6-1-jdk7), but the only answer ("use leiningen") isn't detailed enough for me to figure out.  (Searching clojars for numeric-tower yields... nothing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You install a contrib module by adding its info to :dependencies in your project.clj file. The next time you run `lein` for something, it notices your change and automatically grabs the library for you.

I have [some more detailed instructions written up here](http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/clojure/brief-beginners-guide/libs-management-and-use.html).

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Maven Settings and Repositories](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Maven+Settings+and+Repositories) the repository where all clojure artifacts are deployed is [Sonatype OSS Nexus](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/). If you don't want to go the leiningen or maven way, which I would still advise you to consider also for one-off experiments, you can still download manually all the artifacts from that repository. Specifically, [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/clojure/math.numeric-tower/)'s all the uploaded versions of `clojure.math.numeric-tower`.

Answer (score 3):

I can understand the reluctance to using leiningen though it took me longer to write this sentence than to create a new project.

my usual first stop for this sort of question is http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go
 then clicking latest release and get the artifact I'd and version, then add a line to the project.clj's dependencies section like so

```
[math.numeric-tower "0.0.1"]
```

Comment: This isn't a reluctance to use leiningen.  It's an observation that the bare instruction "use leiningen" doesn't tell you how to accomplish the goal.  Right here you've used two pieces of information I didn't know how to get -- the artifact id, and a version number.

Comment: click on the latest release link under the name on this page, both are listed there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Clojure, you should really also be using either Leiningen or Maven to manage your dependencies. I believe these are the only sane ways to stay on yop of a complex dependency graph as your project gets larger and has more complex build requirements.

For example, I use Maven and have the following in my project's pom.xml to include the numeric dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
        <artifactId>math.numeric-tower</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

All the modular Clojure contrib libraries can be included in the same way.